REST API Pagination for Link Header in ADF and in Postmann
I want to get data from all Pages of REST API using the Link header.
My REST API Link Header is in the following format:
Link: https://URL/v1/requests?per_page=25; rel="first",
https://URL/v1/requests?per_page=25&search_before=IicvNnc1NmIsUjOiQXZzZmZvJye; rel="prev",
https://URL/v1/requests?per_page=25&search_after=eyJvZmZzZXQiOjUsImN1cnNvciIx; rel="next"
How to add "Pagination Rule" in ADF and in Postman for the above Link Header to get data from all Pages?
I tried this URL "https://URL/v1/requests?per_page=25" in Postman and in ADF directly. It works ok. But when I used "https://URL/v1/requests?per_page=25&search_after=eyJvZmZzZXQiOjUsImN1cnNvciIx" URL in Postman. It does not give me data from all Pages.

please explain what is ADF?
